# Am I banned from review queues forever?

Tags: support, review-suspension

My review ban was supposed to be up a month or two ago but now says I'm banned until next September.

The review suspension message is as follows:

> Due to your poor review history as well as no signs of improvement after many review suspensions, you won't be able to use any of the review queues on the site any longer.

Next September will I be able to review posts or will it be updated to September of the following year after that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you have a permanent review suspension.

Unfortunately moderators can only issue a maximum of 365 day suspensions, so it's going to be manually extended occasionally.

Comment: Why can't this be changed? Forever is a bit long.

Comment: An extended incorrect use of review queues  takes a substantial amount of time and moderator effort to detect, stop, and if necessary, clean up and correct bad review outcomes. You've historically shown no attempts to improve when faced with a suspension, which makes you incredibly high risk to bring back. A massive shortage of reviewer reviewers (and mods to keep an eye on reviewers) makes time a valuable resource in very short supply