# How does one recover from a "permanent" review suspension?

Tags: support, review-suspension

In [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402358/6471538) recent answer, Samuel Liew ♦ mentions that a particular user has "a permanent review suspension" on Stack Overflow via continued re-suspension as the date for restoration approaches.

How does one recover from such a "permanent" suspension? I know that "permanent" chat suspensions exist, but that it is [theoretically possible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372796/6471538) to seek and even receive restoration. There are also processes to appeal many other actions, such as site suspension and loss of moderator diamonds.

To be clear, I'm not suggesting that the user in question is currently deserving of having access to the review queues again - I'm simply asking what worthiness of restoration actually looks like to the moderators here (Passage of a significant period of time with no misconduct? Significant positive contributions to the site? A user referendum? Excellent review performance on another network site? Writing an essay about current review queue best practices?).

What is the process for recovering from a "permanent" review suspension? In other words, what would you expect to see from the user in question before you would seriously consider lifting their review ban?

I'm specifically looking for a moderator's viewpoint here rather than speculation. Something like, "It's pretty difficult, but generally I want to see at least five years with no suspensions, at least 10k rep, and a ten page essay on what the user did wrong and what they will do next time. Even then, I would probably refuse at least 50% of the time." would be a good answer.

Comment: *What is the process for recovering from a "permanent" review suspension?* --> the Moderator forget to extend it after 365 days ;)

Comment: If it's actually "permanent", I wouldn't expect one can get out of it, as with any other kind of perma-ban.

Comment: @yivi see my link above. A user was able to get out of a thousand-year "permanent" chat ban by asking nicely. They then promptly got banned again when it was determined that they hadn't actually learned their lesson, but that's beside the point. Suppose the user in question *has* learned their lesson - how would they prove it?

Comment: You're not making a very strong case.

Comment: Reincarnation as a responsible user?

Comment: Again, I wouldn't expect for there to be any kind of regular process to revert such a suspension. If it's permanent, only something exceptional can revert it. A kind of exception that it's hard and undesirable to normativize.

Comment: As the answer you link to states, this "permanent" suspension is not really permanent, as it needs to be prolonged manually. I expect the way to recover from it is just wait and hope the mods forget to extend it, then quickly prove you can review, as you really must have done something exceptional to make moderators put in work every year to keep you from reviewing. As for that user seeking restoration from his chat ban, if you read the history on it it's a clear case for why such restoration shouldn't be granted because he got suspended again soon after, annoying people in the process

Comment: I wouldn't expect them to recover from this.  Bans from the review queue are as lenient as they get, especially given that you can usually come back from them after a year max (manual maximum ban).  If you're stuck at an indefinite ban level, you've messed up enough that the mods see it as *less* work to keep you out of the queues than to let you loose in them.

Comment: I'm finding the next potential question also relevant: Why would a user want to get out of the ban?

Comment: @RobertColumbia FWIW, that forgiven chat user [is now permanently chat banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397976/why-am-i-banned-from-every-single-chat-because-i-spoke-in-one-that-didnt-want-m) (10k link) because they *didn't* learn. Some people just refuse to learn, no matter how many chances you give them.

Comment: On my list of things to read If I reach 10k.

Comment: @DragandDrop it's the JavaScript megaTroll:(

Comment: I seem to recall there being some discussion in the Bad Reviews chat room about whether Samuel Liew should be permitted to use the custom tool he uses to achieve permabans. I'm not sure if that discussion left the chat room.